# $\mathbb{E} \big[ e^{\mathbf{x}^T M_1 \mathbf{x} } \big] \hspace{5 pt}{\rm v.s.} \hspace{5 pt}\mathbb{E} \big[ e^{\mathbf{x}^T M_2 \mathbf{x} } \big]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $p(x)$ be a distribution with zero mean, $\int x p(x) \, dx = 0$. Consider two $n \times n$ symmetric matrices $M_1, M_2$. Is there anyway to compare the following two expectations:
$$
\mathbb{E} \big[ e^{\mathbf{x}^T M_1 \mathbf{x} } \big] \hspace{5 pt}{\rm v.s.} \hspace{5 pt}\mathbb{E} \big[ e^{\mathbf{x}^T M_2 \mathbf{x} } \big]
$$
where $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with i.i.d. components distributed according to $p$.

I am looking for a way to relate this comparison to comparing the determinant of the matrices $M_1,M_2$.

An additional assumption with might help: both $M_1, M_2$ has 0 diagonal, and the other entries are non-negative.

Comment: Perhaps the following 3 observations may help: (1) Since $M_i$ have $0$ diagonal, and the trace is the sum of eigenvalues, is zero, then there must be both real negative and positive eigenvalues, or all are zeros. (2) $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}^T M \mathbf{x}] = \mathbb{E}[trace(\mathbf{x}^T M \mathbf{x})] = trace(M \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T]) = trace(M (\sigma^2)^n I_n) = (\sigma^2)^n trace(M) = 0$, where $\sigma^2$ is variance of $x_k$. (3) Since exp is convex, by Jensen's inequality: $\mathbb{E} \big[ e^{\mathbf{x}^T M \mathbf{x}} \big] \ge e^{\mathbb{E} [\mathbf{x}^T M \mathbf{x}]}$.

Comment: In my previous comment, it should be just $\sigma^2$, not $(\sigma^2)^n$. Got confused for a moment with scalar in the determinant...  But could not edit my comment from yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know for arbitrary distributions. However, if $x\sim N(0,I_n)$, and you are interested in $E[\exp(x^TMx)]$, you may diagonalize $M$ as $\sum_i \lambda_i u_i u_i^T$ with orthonormal $u_i$.
Then the $u_i^Tx$ are iid $N(0,1)$ and $u_i^Tx)^2$ are iid chi-square with 1 degree of fredom. By the explicit formula for the moment generating function given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution,
$$
E[\exp(\lambda_i (u_i^Tx)^2]
= (1-2\lambda_i)^{-1/2}
$$
provided that $\lambda_i<1/2$. By independence,
$E[\exp(x^TMx)]=\prod_i E[\exp(\lambda_i (u_i^Tx)^2]=\prod_i (1-2\lambda_i)^{-1/2}$.

This quantity is also $\det(I_n-2M)^{-1/2}$ if one wishes to involve determinants of related matrices.

If there are two symmetric matrices $M_1,M_2$ and the goal is to compare the ratio $E[\exp(x^TM_1x)]/E[\exp(x^TM_2x)]$ then the question is whether the determinant of $(I_n - 2M_1)(I_n-2M_2)^{-1}$ is greater than 1.

Comment: I needed a general answer/insight. For Gaussian distribution, one can compute the expectation using the Gaussian integral formula, and finds simply the ratio you wrote.